# "Unhandled" exception in ASP .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I got an exception in my log file. The thing is that I have a global exception handler in my Startup.Configure() method:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

and it is get actually called. So the exception is handled. How to suppress this message from being put to the log file?

Thank you!

````
ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.OnReadStarting()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryStart()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.EnsureBufferedAsync(Int32 minCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.FormValueProviderFactory.AddValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IList`1 factories)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.TryCreateAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IList`1 factories)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)```
````

Comment: A very common action of an error handler is precisely to log it, why do you want to ignore it?

Comment: BadHttpRequestException sounds like a Boneheaded except, per this classification: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ Those you sould fix/avoided, never caught (except for logging). Of course there is a small chance it is a Exogenous one. But I really doubt it.

Comment: `UseExceptionHandler` simply ensures that the client gets some sort of response, but the exception is still thrown.

Comment: The reason that I want to ignore it is the fact that the app here works as expected and the user will get the precise error description and could handle it by her/himself. I only want to log errors that indicate that there is an error in app design.

Comment: I found that SO formatting have hidden the first line of Exception message. Fixed it. That should be important.

Answer (score 1):

Reliably logging exceptions is the one thing a global Exception Handler can actually do. Afterwards it should always let the exception go on. For logging it must catch wide, wich means it would catch Fatal Exceptions and those should always be let go. A global handler is way to late to fix anything anymore. It might even be to late to properly log anything anymore, as most stuff is way out of scope by then.

To know how to properly deal with it, we first need to classify it. I use this classificaiton System: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

`BadHttpRequestException` looks like a Boneheaded Exception. Those you should never ignore and ideally never catch. Those you should **fix**.

However as we are dealing with Networking, there is a chance it could be a Exogenous or Vexing Exception. If it is one of those, you should catch it as close to where it is throw and as precisely as possible. Also give the calling code some hint something went wrong, so the expected result is not there. I once wrote this example for a replicated TryParse:

```
//Parse throws ArgumentNull, Format and Overflow Exceptions.
//And they only have Exception as base class in common, but identical handling code (output = 0 and return false).

bool TryParse(string input, out int output){
  try{
    output = int.Parse(input);
  }
  catch (Exception ex){
    if(ex is ArgumentNullException ||
      ex is FormatException ||
      ex is OverflowException){
      //these are the exceptions I am looking for. I will do my thing.
      output = 0;
      return false;
    }
    else{
      //Not the exceptions I expect. Best to just let them go on their way.
      throw;
    }
  }

  //I am pretty sure the Exception replaces the return value in exception case. 
  //So this one will only be returned without any Exceptions, expected or unexpected
  return true;
}
```

The Vexing parts of Parse? Those are caught right there and communicate via the bool return. I had to catch wide or triplicate the handling code, so I did my best with `is` checks to filter later.

For general decent praactices, I do have [one Article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET). Together with the classification above, it is the core of all my Exception Handling decisions.

Comment: Christopher, thank you for the answer! I will examine your links. I really want to catch this exception but I don't know where to do it - the stack trace does not contain any piece of my own code.

Comment: I found that SO formatting have hidden the first line of Exception message. Fixed it. That should be important.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to not disable logging errors because it is one of the main ways on finding users problem.
Anyway if you do want to disable error logging you can do it from the config. Default config file is "appsettings.json" file:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": 6,
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": 6
  }
}
```

This will suppress any error message either from Microsoft or Hosting .
Please note that there is also "appsettings.Development.json" file that is used In Development Environment that you may wish to disable log there too.